# using javascript to get JSON from the controller to display in a view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

This is what I do in the controller(It works fine) :

```
public JsonResult DepartmentList(string id)
{
JsonResult jr = new JsonResult();

var _menu = from a in DataContext.GetDepartment()
            select new { ID = a.ID, Name = a.Name };

jr.Data = _menu.ToList();
jr.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;
return jr;
}
```

And I want to use javascript to take the JSON that I have return in the below controller to display in a list and get the result :

```
<a href="blahblah.com/Products/dep=1?tab=2"> Department name1 </a>
<a href="blahblah.com/Products/dep=2?tab=2"> Department name2 </a>
....
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post a JSON you get back? (Raw JSON)

Comment: I would be nice to know how your JSON looks like. Don't you use .getJSON() or other method's in jQuery to get the JSON ?

Comment: @devdRew : Thanks devdRew , but I really don't know how to know that RAW JSON result, could u tell me how to bug that?

Answer (score 1):

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Answer (score 1):

You could use AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("DepartmentList", new { id = "123" })',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(result) {
        // the result variable here will represent the list returned by your controller
        $.each(result, function() {
            // we are looping through the elements of the list 
            // and each element will have an ID and Name property that
            // you could use here:
            alert('id=' + this.ID + ', name=' + this.Name);
        });
    } 
});
```

For example if you wanted to generate a list of anchors and append them to the end of the body:

```
success: function(result) {
    $.each(result, function() {
        $('body').append(
            $('<a/>', {
                text: this.Name,
                href: 'blahblah.com/Products/dep=' + this.ID + '&tab=2'
            })
        );
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Darin Dimitrov, But I really don't know how to loop the elements. I'm just a pretty new to JSON.

Comment: @socheata, you could use the `$.each`  method as shown in my answer.

Comment: I'm not mean to use the Static parameter like /Products/ , But I want to put the properties of the model, such as Model.ControllerName/Model.ActionName/...

Comment: @socheata, can't you concatenate them: `href: 'blahblah.com/' + this.Property1 + '/dep=' + this.ID + '&tab=2'`? And if you don't know the property names in advance you could use a `for` loop: `for (var propName in this) { ... you could use this[propName] here to get get the value ... }`

Answer (score 1):

Using ajax,

```
$.post("DepartmentList", {id: "yourID"}, ajaxOK);
    function ajaxOK(data){     
      for(i=0; i< data.length; i++){
      $('a:nth-child('+(i+1)+')').text(data[i]);
      }
    }
```